# pdfWriter.write hangs after Encryption

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have been trying to encrypt multiple pdf's by walking through a directory tree.But for some unknow reason the pdfWriter.write comand hangs while processing a big pdf file .there is no error as well and it just stays on that line .Can anyone help .Please note this happens only on the big file and afte encrytion .If i comment out the encryption The files are copied over smoothly.

```
  pdfWriter = PyPDF2.PdfFileWriter()
   

   for folder,subfolders,files in
```

os.walk('C:\Users\xxxx\Downloads'):
for subfolder in subfolders:

```
    for file in files:
    
        p= os.path.join(folder, file)
        filtered =reg.search(file)
        if filtered is None:
            continue
        print(folder)

               

        pdfWriter = PyPDF2.PdfFileWriter()
      
        pdfread = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(open(p, 'rb'))
    
        print(pdfread.numPages)
        for pageNum in range(pdfread.numPages):
            pageObj = pdfread.getPage(pageNum)
            pdfWriter.addPage(pageObj)
            
            
       # pdfWriter.encrypt('xxxxx') 

        newpdf =open(file + '_encryted.pdf' ,'wb')
       
        pdfWriter.write(newpdf) (gets stuck here )
```

Comment: There is much code commented out here. it's hard to tell what you intend us to mentally put back. Please edit your question to include all and only code that is supposed to be there, that runs without us having to fix it, and that illustrates the problem.

Comment: Have edited the code .Hope this help .I have also mentioned the point where it gets stuck.